# BUG: When passing django.messages variable through HTML tag

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, django-messages

`messages.info(request, 'Attendance Ready To Be Taken!')`

Over here i use django messages to send a string to the user

```
{% for message in messages %} 
{% if message == 'Attendance Ready To Be Taken!' %}
  <div class="alert success"> 
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>   
      <strong>SUCCESS!</strong> {{message}} 
  </div> 

{% else %}
<div class="alert"> 
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>   
      <strong>WARNING!</strong> {{message}} 
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, although the string is clearly the same..it doesn’t output SUCCESS message.

It can display the message indeed..but I want to filter if it’s a success message to be green..and error message to be red..just for user interface to warn users

```
.alert { 
     padding: 20px; 
     background-color: #f44336; 
     color: white; 
     opacity: 1; 
     transition: opacity 0.6s; 
     margin-bottom: 15px; 
} 
  
.alert.success {background-color: #04AA6D;}
```

Above is the CSS code for the two messages' styles for your reference.

The message “Attendance ready to be taken” should be showing green..but it’s red color in the webpage.

So I guess it didn’t fulfill the conditional 'if' statement. That’s why it goes to 'else', and becomes red color.

But I'm not sure why it doesn’t. Because the message displayed is the same thing as the string i compared it with..

Does anyone know what's causing this weird bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sent the `info` message, so its tag is `info`.

The best to apply CSS classes dynamically is to make use of [`Message tags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/messages/#message-tags).

Then define the tags of messages in the view as:

```py
messages.info(request, 'Attendance Ready To Be Taken!', extra_tags='success')
```

Then this `success` tag will also become class in the element dynamically.

Use in the template as:

```html
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div  class="alert {% if message.tags %} {{message.tags}} {% endif %}"> 
            <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>   
            <strong>SUCCESS!</strong> {{message}} 
        </div> 
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

To send `error` message which has `error` tag by default:

```py
messages.error(request, 'Attendance Not completed !', extra_tags='red')
```

Then the `red` tag will also become class.

The template can be same just need to add this css:

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This way it works dynamically.

---

### Another possible solution:

You can use [`MESSAGE_LEVEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-MESSAGE_LEVEL), they allow us to group by type so that they can be filtered or displayed differently in views and templates. Level is an integer describing the type of the message.

```
Level      Value
DEBUG       10
INFO        20
SUCCESS     25
WARNING     30
ERROR       40
```

Then with your current code simply check the message in template using `{% if message.level == 20 %}`, so:

```html
{% for message in messages %} 
    {% if message.level == 20 %}
        <div class="alert success"> 
            <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>   
            <strong>SUCCESS!</strong> {{message}} 
            </div> 

            {% else %}
            <div class="alert"> 
            <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>   
            <strong>WARNING!</strong> {{message}} 
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Alright..I understand..Thank you so much for the detailed explanation..I really appreciate it..